# Using angulartics2 without a defined provider

Tags: .net, angular, angulartics2

I am using Angulartics2 as it seems a flexible solution to collect analytics from an Angular site.

As yet I do not know if we are going to use a specified provider, for now I just want to send the data to the server and store it locally.

Is this possible with Angulartics2, or would I have to write my own provider just to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do it is to write your own provider and do a pull-request to get it included.

https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2#for-other-providers

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I ask as I'd be surprised if someone hadn't needed to do what Im doing and Im not sure how to write a provider. Any ideas?